# ERR:insecure response with apache

Tags: apache, express, ssl, https

Apache server is proxying requests to express server running on 9999

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.aonesalons.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/aonesalons.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/aonesalons.com.key
    # <Proxy *>
    #   Order allow,deny
    #    Allow from all
  # </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9999/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I hit, `api.aonesalons.com` in browser, my request goes to the server.

from my application frontend, that is also served over https by apache, when any of the api url's are called,

it always returns

```
ERR_FAILED or ERR_INSECURE_CONNECTION
```

**Edit:**

In browser console in security tab, the certificate is valid totally. I have tried proxying requests to the https version of the express server as well but no difference. It started happening after moving to https.

As soon I start to use Cloudflare as a proxy for api.aonesalons.com, api.aonesalons.com returns my client end application and doesn't hit my API's. I am using apache to proxy api.aonesalons.com to 9999 server and *.aonesalons.com to client folder with static application content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SSLLabs report for api.aonesalons.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.aonesalons.com&latest):

> Trusted - No -  NOT TRUSTED

A closer look at the certificate shows:

> Subject - CloudFlare Origin Certificate
>   Issuer - CloudFlare, Inc.

This is not a certificate intended for direct access by the public. It is trusted only by Clouldflare itself and is intended to secure the path between the Cloudflare CDN and the server protected by this CDN, see [Introducing CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/).

> In browser console, in security tab, certificate is valid totally.

I don't know what you did to you browser but maybe you explicitly trusted the Cloudflare CA. When visiting the site with a browser I get the expected warning:

> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

My guess is that you've  tried to protect your site with the Cloudflare CDN but failed to adjust the DNS settings properly in order to let Cloudflare manage the relevant parts of your DNS.

Comment: I was not proxying request to api.aonesalons.com through cloudflare but was using the ssl certificate provided by them. "This is not a certificate intended for direct access by the public. It is trusted only by Clouldflare itself and is intended to secure the path between the Cloudflare CDN and the server protected by this CDN, " This made it clear what the problem was. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: As soon I start to use cloudflare as proxy for api.aonesalons.com, api.aonesalons.com returns my client end application and doesnot hit my API's. I am using apache to proxy api.aonesalons.com to 9999 server and *.aonesalons.com to client folder with static application content

Comment: @Simrankaur: your last comment is essentially a different question, i.e. how to configure use of Cloudflare properly in your specific setup. Please ask it as a new question and provide the necessary details about your current setup in the new question.